# Scroll para a próxima seção

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

já pesquisei em vários lugares mas até agora não encontrei como fazer esse efeito.

O que eu preciso é que o scroll fique exatamente igual esse site: http://www.takeitapp.co/en

Ou seja, sempre que o usuário der um scroll o site irá para a próxima seção.

Alguém sabe o nome disso ou como se faz?

Obrigado!

Comment: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu estava procurando, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bom dia!

Existem alguns plugins para brincar com o scroll e com efeitos de parallax. Os que conheço são:

[Scrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/),
[StellarJS](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/),
[Skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/),
[ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/)

Utilizando algum desses pacotes e mais um pouco de javascript você já consegue fazer o efeito desejado mas, se ainda assim precisar de algo mais simples, existe o [FullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage), que serve justamente para separar o site em seções como um slide vertical.